# Removing and adding key-value from JSON file using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have an json file as follows below-

```
{
  "key1": [
    "value1"
  ],
  "key2": [
    "value2"
  ],
  "key3": [
    "value3"
  ],
  "key4": {
    "name": "value4"
  },
  "key5": [
    {
      "field1": "abc",
      "field2": "xyz"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to remove field 2 from key5 array and add another field say field3  in key5 array using jq
I tried various way but couldn't figure it how to do this in single command.
Can you please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that the insert and deletion keys (`field2` and `field3`) are also dynamic, not just the inserted value.

- Use `--arg` and `--argjson` to initialize variables with values from outside the filter, here `field2` as a string and `{"field3": "new"}` as a JSON object
- Use the update operator `|=` on the element you want to change, here `.key5[]`.

  - Note: `.key5` is an array, not an object, thus it has no fields. But the array does contain objects as its elements. Using `.key5[]` to access the array elements will update **all** objects in the array. To update just one of them, say, the first one, use `.key[0]` instead.
- Use `delpaths` to delete a given path, here the top-level field `[$delkey]`.
- Use simple addition `+` to add a new key/value pair as object, here `$add`.

```sh
jq --arg delkey 'field2' --argjson addobj '{"field3": "new"}' '
  .key5[] |= delpaths([[$delkey]]) + $addobj
' input.json
```

```json
{
  "key1": [
    "value1"
  ],
  "key2": [
    "value2"
  ],
  "key3": [
    "value3"
  ],
  "key4": {
    "name": "value4"
  },
  "key5": [
    {
      "field1": "abc",
      "field3": "new"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/mAjuXE6lt1)

If you want to provide the new object's key and value separately, i.e. as strings, not as a pre-composed JSON, you need a third input variable

```sh
jq --arg delkey 'field2' --arg addkey 'field3' --arg addval 'new' '
  .key5[] |= (delpaths([[$delkey]]) | .[$addkey] = $addval)
' input.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7uN6nVLOCG)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Since I wanted to check the  field1 value before deleting field2 ,I got it working by adding select operation. Thanks a lot for answer.

Comment: It's nice to know that we can do `.key5[] |= delpaths([["field2"]]) + {field3}` and use `+`  to combine two operations to `|=`. https://jqplay.org/s/fP_rXo-NYP

Answer (score 1):

`.key5[] |= ( ... )` allows you to modify each element of the array found at `.key5`.

Therein, we can use the usual commands for deleting and adding fields.

```
jq '.key5[] |= ( del( .field2 ) | .field3 = "foo" )'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/fsHuKOnO-K) in jqplay

Here's a variation where the value to add is provided as a command-line argument:

```
jq --arg val foo '.key5[] |= ( del( .field2 ) | .field3 = $val )'
```

Comment: brillant......!

Comment: works like a charm. Thank you so much. it really helped me in understanding how |= works.

Answer (score 0):

Try filter:

```
del(.key5[0].field2) | .key5[0] |= .+{field3:"foo"}
```

Output:

```
{
  "key1": [
    "value1"
  ],
  "key2": [
    "value2"
  ],
  "key3": [
    "value3"
  ],
  "key4": {
    "name": "value4"
  },
  "key5": [
    {
      "field1": "abc",
      "field3": "foo"
    }
  ]
}
```

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/EB8MpWRxU2